# How to pass Animated Value to navigation header component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-navigation

In one of my screen, I have a ScrollView and when I scroll it animates a navigation header.
in my screen file
I have something like this.

```
const translationY = new Value(0);

const headeropacity = interpolate(translationY, {
  inputRange: [0, 300, 500],
  outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
  extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP
});

/* I need to pass to the navigation header */
React.useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setParams({
    opacity: headerOpacity,
  });
}, [navigation, headerOpacity]);
```

And in my custom header file

```
const opacity = scene.route.params.opacity;

return (
  <MyCustomHeader style={{opacity}} />
)
```

And I expected(?) I got error.

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
>   setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a
>   dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render

How can I pass animated value to other screen(page) correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the translationY is undefined before passing the param.

So in a normal case, you will check the translationY this way:

```
 if (!translationY) {
     navigation.setParams({ translationY });
 }
```

And you handle the animated value on the header component, havent tried to pass directly an animated opacity so i cant confirm, but this work for passing animated values